# Why can't I get JMX to run with Tomcat8 through CATALINA_OPTS?

Tags: java, jmx, tomcat8

According to https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/monitoring.html#Introduction I should be able to active JMX by setting some env variables on `CATALINA_OPTS`. I've done this:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

Some places seem to suggest I need `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` in `$CATALINA_OPTS/lib` which I have:

```
$ ls -l /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/lib/catalina-jmx-remote.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13608 Jan 18 23:05 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/lib/catalina-jmx-remote.jar
```

I've also made sure the environment variable is properly set:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/20893/environ
LANG=en_USLANGUAGE=en_US:PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/binHOME=/srv/tomcatLOGNAME=tomcatUSER=tomcatSHELL=TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/oracle/jdk1.8.0_112CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.37CATALINA_BASE=/srv/tomcat/catalina/tomcatCATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.16.29.134 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Despite this, JMX is not listening on 1099 and I cannot connect to it:

```
$ netstat --listen | grep 1099
```

If I run a regular java program with:

```
$ java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.16.29.134 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false HelloWorld
```

This also seems to work if I pass it as args when starting tomcat:

```
/opt/java/oracle/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java \
  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/srv/tomcat/catalina/%i/conf/logging.properties \
  -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager \
  -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
  -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/endorsed \
  -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.37 \
  -Dcatalina.base=/srv/tomcat/catalina/%i \
  -Djava.io.tmpdir=/srv/tomcat/catalina/%i/temp \
  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.16.29.134 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
  -classpath "/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" \
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

So why doesn't `CATALINA_OPTS` get picked up like the documentation suggests? What is it I'm missing?

Comment: where exactly do you set the catalina.opts? On the shell? it might be possible that your startup script for starting tomcat overwrites them.

Comment: It's set in a systemd env file. I'm not sure when it would manage to overwrite it since systemd is invoking bin/java like above, and the process was at least initialized with that env according to /proc.

Comment: if it might be systemd related you might want to add the serverOS as tag, and the systemd version in case someone else knows details about that specific situation

Comment: You mention systemd; here's an article for [Centos 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7), and one for [Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).  In particular, see their example `/etc/systemd/tomcat.service` files -- and the fact that they use start/stop scripts (which should Do The Right Thing(tm)) rather than invoking `java` directly from the systemd file.

Comment: did you refresh systemd configuration via `systemctl daemon-reload` ?

Comment: @GioMac Yes. But also as you can see from /proc the env is being passed.

Comment: You should set them up in setenv.sh
CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.whatever1
  -Dcom.sun.whatever2

Comment: Try once putting all Java parameter in "setenv.sh" under $CATALINA_HOME/bin